# How to create a timer on a new thread

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer, picturebox

I recently asked a question as to how I would get a vertical line to sweep from left to right across a Picturebox.  There were shapes in the Picturebox and the vertical line had to indicate when it crossed one.
I had an answer that worked great.

```
Private lineX As Integer = 0

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lineX += 5

    If lineX > PictureBox1.Width Then
        lineX = 0
    End If

    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black,
                        New Point(lineX, 0),
                        New Point(lineX, PictureBox1.Height))
End Sub
```

However, I find that when I move the mouse around in the Picturebox, the vertical line stops, starts or slows down.  From looking online, I think that a timer on a different thread might be the answer.

Could someone suggest a solution to this?

Comment: There's not really any such thing as a timer on a different thread. You could have a timer that doesn't raise it's events on the UI thread, but that doesn't really help you because the `Paint` event is still going to be executed on the UI thread and I'm pretty sure you need to call `Invalidate` on the UI thread too.

Comment: Thanks, do you think then that there's no way to stop the vertical line from stalling when the mouse is moved?

Comment: `when I move the mouse around in the Picturebox...`  What are you doing in the MouseMove event that's causing that?

Comment: I have a list(Of Points) approximately 100 items long.  As the line moves across the picturebox it checks to see if a point in the list is being crossed, if it is it changes the shape under the point.  A use is able to add or delete a point with the mouse pointer.  It works well except for the line stalling.   Thanks for replying

Comment: If you want better help, try editing your post with the MouseMove code.  You might be doing something inefficient that's slowing things down.  We don't know.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem.  I went through the MouseMouse and Paint code again.  Remed it all out then replaced until I found the code that was slowing it down,  I've rewritten it more efficiently.  Line is not stalling.  Thanks for the hint

Comment: I believe that I also mentioned in a previous answer that it is more efficient to calculate the smallest area that may have changed and pass that when you call `Invalidate`, rather than repainting the entire control. It's the actual painting of pixels on screen that is the slow part so it is worth making the effort to reduce that. You could calculate the smallest `Rectangle` that contains both the old line and the new and pass that to `Invalidate`. You could also calculate two smaller `Rectangles` that contain one line each and call `Invalidate` twice.

Comment: See an old example of mine [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?426684). Note that the call to `Update` in that code is not really required.

Comment: Thanks , yes I see that.  Create a new shape from the dimensions of the shape already altered, increase the size by one pixel to make sure everything is included, then force an invalidate of just that area.  I adjusted my code  and there is quite a difference.  Many thanks.   Also, that whole post is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the accuracy of the movement by taking into account the effectively elapsed time:

```vb
Private lineX As Integer = 0
Private lastDateTime As Date?

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim now = Date.Now
    If lastDateTime.HasValue Then
        lineX += CInt(5 * (now - lastDateTime.Value).Milliseconds / Timer1.Interval)
    Else
        lineX += 5
    End If
    lastDateTime = now

    If lineX > PictureBox1.Width Then
        lineX = 0
    End If
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black,
                        New Point(lineX, 0),
                        New Point(lineX, PictureBox1.Height))
End Sub
```

Note that I moved the code changing the line position into the `PictureBox1_Paint` method to get the exact time at which the line is drawn.

Painting can be delayed after `PictureBox1.Invalidate()` and painting can also occur in other situations, e.g., when the window is resized or moved around etc.

Some calls to `PictureBox1_Paint` can even be dropped if the system is busy.

Even after these changes the movement will not be perfect. WinForms is just not the right system for gaming like things.

Comment: Many thanks, copied the code but cant get the line moving, looking to see whats gone wrong.

Comment: Have you enabled the timer? Either set the `Enabled` property to `True` in the properties window if you have added the Timer as component to your form or call `Timer1.Start()` in Form_Load. Note also that I changed `lastDateTime.Value - now` to `now - lastDateTime.Value`.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see the edit.  I have it moving now but it isn't smooth, it jerks a lot and still delays with the mouse movement.

Comment: You can't avoid that, because the Paint event is just not called at even intervals. It is the Windows operating system which determines when `Timer1_Tick` and `PictureBox1_Paint` is called and you cannot change it.

Comment: Would you say then that there was no way in VB.Net to stop the mouse from effecting the line movement?  Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Everything which happens on your system affects the line movement, because Windows is a multitasking operating system. Your application will be interrupted all the time in favor of other applications, system services and drivers.

Comment: You could use [SikaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/) for faster drawing.